# помогите с написанием цикла для localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery

в коде видно что выводтся элементы стикер из localstorage,но проблема в том что выводятся все элементы в стикере сразу а мне надо чтоб поочередно

```
let sto = [localStorage.getItem("sticker")];

pushResult();

$("#textInput").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() !== "") {   
    sto.push($(this).val())
    localStorage.setItem("sticker",sto);

    pushResult();
  }
});

function pushResult() { 
  $('#result').html('')
  $.each(sto, function(key, value) {
    $('#result').append(`<li key="${key}">${value}</li>`); 
    document.getElementById("textInput").value = "";
  });
};
```

Comment: А что у вас лежит тут `localStorage.getItem("sticker")`?

Comment: В `localStorage`/`sessionStorage` можно хранить только строковые данные. Поэтому перед записью преобразуйте массив/объект в JSON-строку, а при получении - выполняйте обратное преобразование.

Comment: я пишу расширение для заметок в стикере хранятся введенные пользователем данные

Comment: нужен пример данных, так же то что выводится и то что вы хотите получить, из вопроса непонятно